# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isMembershipPriceSet()

Tags: error, paypal

I have an error when paying via PayPal on a contribution page. This error arrives after the payment, it does not show the thank you page and re-proposes the form to make the payment and the thank you email doesn't go out. I can't understand the php error log which is as follows (php error log)

> [18-Dec-2023 21:37:23 Europe/Rome] PHP Warning:  foreach() argument
> must be of type array|object, null given in
> /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php
> on line 1442 [18-Dec-2023 21:37:23 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:
> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isMembershipPriceSet() on
> null in
> /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php:1193
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php(1173):
> CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->getFormContext()
> #1 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php(344):
> CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->isMembershipPriceSet()
> #2 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(738):
> CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main->buildQuickForm()
> #3 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(76):
> CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
> #4 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203):
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform()
> #5 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103):
> HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
> #6 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
> #7 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(322):
> CRM_Core_Controller->run()
> #8 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
> #9 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
> #10 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
> #11 /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(418):
> CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
> #12 /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler()
> #13 /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #14 /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #15 /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(830): do_action_ref_array()
> #16 /home/******/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1336): WP->main()
> #17 /home/******/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
> #18 /home/******/public_html/index.php(17): require('...')
> #19 {main}   thrown in /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php
> on line 1193

the error you see on the response page is the following
Failed to update contribution in database

the error in the log viewer is as follows
1098    2023-12-18 22:04:20+0100    [error] CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm::completeTransaction CRM_Core_Exception: DB Error: no such field
1096    2023-12-18 22:04:20+0100    [info] Contribution 122 updated successfully

php 8.1
CiviCRM 5.68
the extension for Paypal checkout is Omnipay multiprocessor

Thank you in advance for your precious help